# What does the TO DO button in GoSMS do?

Tags: sms

In [GoSMS](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.jb.mms), an incoming SMS is usually shown within a popup containing buttons like DELETE / TO DO / OPEN.

What functionality does TO DO provide?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it closes the popup alert but leaves the message marked unread, whereas the close button (the `X`) will mark it as read and close the popup.

Edit: This seems to be supported by [this comment](http://gosms.goforandroid.com/?p=169#comment-68) from their website.